# How to post to Blogger via Google API in C#

Tags: c#, api, blogs, blogger

I created a method to update my Blogger with the Google API (newest version) in C#. I found some solutions, but I have an error while running the app. There is a codeline, that I can't execute. This part of code is in a try {}, but there is no exception message, and the code in catch {} don't run. I can't figure out what's the problem. I have 2 solutions to test, but none of them working for me. Please help me find out whats the problem, I try to solve this for days...

Sorry for my English, I hope You can understand my problem.

Different solutions is marked with #1 and #2.

```
public static bool AddPost(string title, string bodyHTML, string[] labels, string username, string password, string blogurl)
    {
        Service service = new Service("blogger", "Updater");
        service.Credentials = new GDataCredentials(username, password);
        AtomEntry newPost = new AtomEntry();
        newPost.Title.Text = title;
        newPost.Content = new AtomContent();
        newPost.Content.Content = bodyHTML;
        newPost.Content.Type = "html";
        foreach (string label in labels)
        {
            AtomCategory cat = new AtomCategory();
            cat.Scheme = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#");
            cat.Term = label;
            newPost.Categories.Add(cat);
        }
        AtomEntry response = null;
        try
        {
            #1------------------------------------------------------
            Uri blogFeedUri = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + "BLOG_ID" + "/posts/default");
            response = service.Insert(blogFeedUri, newPost);

            #2------------------------------------------------------
            response = service.Insert(new Uri(blogurl + "feeds/posts/default"), newPost);
        }
        catch (GDataRequestException exception)
        {
            if (exception.ResponseString == "Blog has exceeded rate limit or otherwise requires word verification for new posts")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        if (response == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont try Google Blogger API v3? Install it with NuGet in VS!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you replace the "BLOG_ID" with number strings in following your code,
...
            Uri blogFeedUri = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + "BLOG_ID" + "/posts/default");

Right?

Comment: I had the same very issue when I upgraded my Google API from 1.4 to 1.80.  found this articles on the Blogger Developer's blog.  http://code.blogger.com/2011/06/clarifying-recent-changes-to-bloggers.html